# For which program is this repository?: http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu

Tags: repository

When I type "sudo apt update" to Terminal, I also get these rows:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

For which program is this repository?

Thank you and greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Literally point your browser at http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu/

and descend into:

`dists/eoan/main/binary-arm64/`

I have chosen `eoan` here because there is no `focal`, and `eoan` is the most recent.

You will find a file called `Packages.xz`. Download it and open it. It will list all the packages that are inside this PPA (or are supposed to be).

These are:

```
backintime-common
backintime-gnome
backintime-kde
backintime-kde4
backintime-notify
backintime-qt
backintime-qt4
```

Comment: Thank you for help! But how do you open this link. All I get in browser is "Not Found.
The requested URL /bit-team/stable/ubuntu/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Are you sure? Just click the link. It takes me to a page called `Index of /bit-team/stable/ubuntu`.

Comment: Also check the human-oriented page on upper level - https://launchpad.net/~bit-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable .